# Contact pressure representation in Abaqus

Tags: scripting, abaqus

The main question is connected with extracting the contact pressure from .odb file.
The issue is described in three facts written below:

Imagine that we have simple 3D contact model in Abaqus/CAE

1.If we make a plot of CPRESS on a deformed shape in visualisation module, we'll get a one value of CPRESS for each node. The same (one value for one node) we will get if we request XYdata field output for all frames. And this all seems to be ok, because as far as I know Abaqus CAE use averaging for surface output (CPRESS) to make it possible to request as nodal output.

2.If we use "Probe values" instrument to examine CPRESS value in node, we'll get four values for one node. It still seems to be ok, because, i suppose, it shows the values befor averaging.

3.If we request CPRESS value from command window using this script:
odb.steps['step_name'].frames[frame_number].fieldOutputs['CPRESS'].getSubset(region='node_path').values
length of this vector of CPRESS values in a single node may be from 1 to 6 depending on a chosen node. And the quantity of CPRESS valuse got using this method have no connection with the quantity got using method 2.

So the trick is that I can't inderstand how the vector of CPRESS in node is forming. 
Found very little information about this topic in Abaqus Manual.
Hope somebody may help)

Answer (score 0):

Probe Values, extacts the CPRESS values for the whole element. It shows the face number and its node IDs toghether with their corresponding values.